# Database schema for Collaboration software

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I'm designing a database for Musician hiring and Collaboration application.
**Main Idea-**
There are two types of users - **Musicians** and **Listeners**. Musicians can upload audio/video posts and can send collaboration request to other musicians.
Listeners can see musician posts and send hire request to them.

**Tables structure**

1. Users
2. Posts
3. Likes
4. Comments
5. Hire
6. Collaborate

Should I make separate tables for Musicians and Listeners? They have many common fields but only musician can create posts.

Comment: FYI, I removed the PHP tag since the question is about database architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about splitting the users table up?

If they have the same type of data, leave it as one table. If the have a lot of differences you might separate them. Note there is nothing wrong separating them but best practices is to create collections holding the same data. Your database is not responsible to decide what a specific user can do, that belongs to your access controlling code.
Also ask yourself question like, what if a musician wants to hire another musician? You would end up having redundancy which is usually bad design in relational databases.

You may also create two additional tables with additional attributes for each type of users but keep common data in the users table. For example each user probably has a username and a password.

Answer (score 0):

You can ad a *user_type* field in the users table and differentiate users by *user_type*.